# how to install pr2_simulator on lunar?

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed pr2_simulator,and launched "pr2_gazebo pr2.launch" with info: ResourceNotFound: pr2_controller_manager.
I'd like to know how to install it on LUNAR and I'm a beginner.
many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270292/how-to-install-pr2_simulator-on-lunar?/) by [camtoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/31798/camtoto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

You can clone the pr2_mechanism repo from Github ([here](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_mechanism)) in your catkin source directory and build it.

> cd ~/catkin_ws/src

> git clone https://github.com/PR2/pr2_mechanism

> cd ../ && catkin_make

If any depedencies will appear, search in the PR2 github [page](https://github.com/PR2) to install them.

---

Originally posted by [dchatzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28706/dchatzi/) with karma: 16 on 2018-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0